# Make cells that were populated with Concentrate function have standalone data instead of the formula

Tags: database, wordpress, google-sheets, woocommerce

Below I have linked my CSV for a store (woocommerce), I have columns C and D pulling data from other columns. So when I export as CSV and upload to woocommerce the data from those cells isn't represented correctly, what I need to do is make those cells actually contain the text that is displayed using the concentrate function.

Is there an easy way to go about this, or am I bound to copy paste from two columns and add text that repeats?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/189DoiV2LwV5JrXqPVAZTL9ww5hAq2Ws7_IdWqsd7mqo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not clear what is the programming issue and there isn't enough information about the research efforts made prior to posting the question. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask] to learn about the basic workings and guidelines of this site.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. I have selected the whole column that used the formula to generate the value (text) and copied it, then I have pasted it somewhere else in the same document, deleted the original column and pasted the value column in its place.